# Get rid of Negative signs from whole Column

Tags: google-apps-script, truncate

I have a column in which there are some values as $##.00 and some values are -$##.00

What script should I use to convert -$##.00 values to $##.00 values, i.e. converting all numbers to positive?

I tried following that is far from working;

```
function removNeg(){
  var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.openById('.........');
  var ss = sheet.getSheets()[0];
  var range = ss.getRange("M2:M");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var absValues = Math.abs(values);
  range.setValues(absValues);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to modify the negative numbers to the positive numbers using Google Apps Script.
- You want to achieve this at the cells of `M2:M`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
function removNeg(){
  var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.openById('.........');
  var ss = sheet.getSheets()[0];
  var range = ss.getRange("M2:M");
  var values = range.getValues();

  var absValues = values.map(([r]) => [!r || isNaN(r) ? r : Math.abs(r)]);  // Modified

  range.setValues(absValues);

  // range.setNumberFormats(values.map(([r]) => ["$##.00"]));
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to also modify the number format from `-$##.00` to `$##.00`, please use `range.setNumberFormats(values.map(([r]) => ["$##.00"]));` of the last line.
- Please use this modified script with enabling V8.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)